# GoogleAds PHP SoapFault - AdError.CANNOT_SET_FIELD @ operations[0].operand.ad.url

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am using the library `googleads/googleads-php-lib` from github.

I am trying to create a text ad, but I am getting an error that I cannot set the URL field.  The code has been working for quite some time but has suddenly stopped due to this error.

The SoapFault exception that is thrown is:

> [AdError.CANNOT_SET_FIELD @ operations[0].operand.ad.url]

My code is as follows:

```
require_once('Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php');
$developerToken = '*removed*';
$clientCustomerId = '*removed*';
$userAgent = 'test';
$settingsIniPath = './vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/settings.ini';
$oAuth = array(
    'client_id' => '*removed*',
    'client_secret' => '*removed*',
    'refresh_token' => '*removed*',
);
$adWordsUser = new AdWordsUser(null, $developerToken, $userAgent, $clientCustomerId, $settingsIniPath, $oAuth);
$adWordsUser->SetDefaultVersion('v201409');
$adGroupId = *removed*;

$textAd = new TextAd();
$textAd->headline = 'headline text';
$textAd->description1 = 'description1 text';
$textAd->description2 = 'description2 text';
$textAd->displayUrl = 'www.example.com';
$textAd->url = 'http://www.example.com/';

$adGroupAd = new AdGroupAd($adGroupId, $textAd);
$operations = array(new AdGroupAdOperation($adGroupAd, null, 'ADD'));
$adGroupAdService = $adWordsUser->GetService('AdGroupAdService');
$result = $adGroupAdService->mutate($operations);
```

I am not sure what could be causing this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

got caught with that too. The problem seems to be that "url" is no longer supported, you have to use "targetUrls" of upgraded URLs API instead:

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.cz/2015/05/reminder-adwords-destination-urls-will.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I also posted the question as an issue on the GH project and got this response: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues/91#issuecomment-121147319  They said to use `finalUrls`.  What's the difference between `targetUrls` and `finalUrls` ?